# como é possível após o usuário ser deslogado do sistema por inatividade, o mesmo voltar para a mesma tela que estava após o login

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, razor

Como sou novo e estou aprendendo mvc, gostaria de saber, como é possível após o usuário ser deslogado do sistema por inatividade, o mesmo voltar para a mesma tela que estava. Sei que o código já o redireciona toda vez para página da home, mas gostaria de deixar isso dinâmico, para ele voltar para a ultima página antes de ser derrubada sua sessão.

Comment: Salve, em cache ou localstorage a ultima rota acessada, antes da função de deslogar, ao logar, verifique se possui alguma rota salve e redirecione-o

Comment: Pergunta ampla, sem contexto e geralmente as linguagens que utilizam frameworks CMS fazem isso ...